# Unable to import Eclipse project in intellij

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea, import

I am new to IntelliJ, trying to import the eclipse project by following the steps explained on the website https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/import-project-from-eclipse-page-1.html and I can import pretty much all the projects except one. The one I really want to import is pretty big includes selenium and testing and doesn't contain an 'src folder'. Every time I try to import I don't see the project/module folder but only External Libraries as I have shown in the picture below.

[image]

Comment: Are there any errors/warnings in idea.log ("Help | Show Log in..")?

Comment: what do you expect? There is no `src` folder as you mentioned. Is there another folder that should show up?

Comment: please post your folder structure.

Comment: @y.bedrov there are no errors shown

Comment: @Peter There are many packages in the project each contains around 3 classes I am using testng so I don't necessarily require src folder to run those packages. And it works completely well in eclipse

Comment: @DaveRanjan even I want to share the folder structure to provide the complete context but it contains work-related sensitive information that won't be appropriate to share, sorry.

Comment: rather than importing an eclipse project, can't you import the same project from local directory? 
In InteliIJ,
File->New-> Project from existing source > (select the project folder)

line 1  -ProjectFolderName
       2    --ProjectFolderName 
       3        -proj files
sometimes, while importing the project, if you import the project folder(line 1) ,rather than line 2. since both have same name. then the case happens which you showed in the screenshot. IntelliJ fails to import the correct project files. that's when you see something like "external libraries" only.

Comment: Ok, sounds like an uncommon setup. Can't help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
rather than importing an eclipse project, can't you import the same project from local directory? 

In InteliIJ, 
File->
   New-> 
       ->Project from existing source 
         -> (select the project folder) 
Also,

Line
:

   Directory Structure :
         1   -ProjectFolderName 
         2     -ProjectFolderName    
         3       -proj files 

Note: sometimes, while importing the project, if you import the project folder(line 1) ,rather than line 2. since both have same name. then the case happens which you showed in the screenshot. IntelliJ fails to import the correct project files. that's when you see something like "external libraries" only.
```

Comment: Okay I followed your steps and it worked  but while importing the project instead of choosing import from external model and selecting eclipse, I clicked on Create project from existing sources

Comment: that is fine, the aim is to import the project to intelliJ, is what i think

Comment: if it solved your problem, u can mark the answer as helpful or  correct or upvote